# IE8 CSS Hover Image Not Clickable JQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, onclick, hover

I have an image which is has an onmousedown event . When I hover over it, it displays a seperate image. My hover code looks like this:

```
            $(".baur").hover(
                            function () {
                                    $(".hoverbaur").show();
                            },
```

I've been using this code for a while, although today I tested in IE8 and the link doesn't work! Initially, I set hoverbaur css display to none and then the JQuery alters this on hover. I know I could link the hover image also, but there's many of them. I was hoping that there was a CSS solution that would make the hovering image visible, yet have the onclick event of the image underneath it still execute.

I suppose my other question would be why does this work in FF and Chrome?

Sure thing! An example image looks like this

```
<img class="baur" onmousedown="showDiv()">
<img class="hoverbaur" style="display:none">

function showDiv(){
$("#welcome").show
}
```

Any advice would help,
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your html and more complete javascript?

Comment: Why did you not user id on your image ? I dont understand why you use class and specify style on your image like class="hoverbaur" style="display:none"

Comment: I actually had the style set in a seperate css sheet, I just threw it in to show you whats its style was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `show()` method mis-typed as `show`. It should be:

```
$("#welcome").show();
```

Note: jQuery allows you to make your code unobtrusive. You should avoid using inline javascript/css.